# Type 10 is not supported error on intellij when I trying to run my code with postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, scala, apache-spark, jdbc

I am new to postgresql and have been trying to connect my scala projects on Intellij to postgresql but I am getting this error.

```
[error] org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have configured the pg_hba.conf file to include the client'
s IP address or subnet, and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the driver.
[error]         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:610)
[error]         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:203)
[error]         at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65)
[error]         at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:149)
[error]         at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:35)
[error]         at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
[error]         at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:47)
[error]         at org.postgresql.jdbc42.AbstractJdbc42Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc42Connection.java:21)
[error]         at org.postgresql.jdbc42.Jdbc42Connection.<init>(Jdbc42Connection.java:28)
[error]         at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:415)
[error]         at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:282)
[error]         at slick.jdbc.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.scala:101)
[error]         at slick.jdbc.DataSourceJdbcDataSource.createConnection(JdbcDataSource.scala:68)
[error]         at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.<init>(JdbcBackend.scala:494)
[error]         at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.createSession(JdbcBackend.scala:46)
[error]         at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.createSession(JdbcBackend.scala:37)
[error]         at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession(BasicBackend.scala:250)
[error]         at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession$(BasicBackend.scala:249)
[error]         at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession(JdbcBackend.scala:37)
[error]         at slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.run(BasicBackend.scala:275)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
[error]         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
[error]         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[error] (slick) org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have configured the pg_hba.conf file to include the
 client's IP address or subnet, and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the driver.
```

I have already configure the pg_hba file but still could not get it running.

Please Suggest me a solution for this problem.

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

Comment: Upgrade your JDBC driver